# jest testing function call inside another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

Is it possible to test startServer() call once launcApp is called?

```
import { Server } from './Server/Server';

export class Launcher {
    
    private server: Server;

    public constructor() {
        this.server = new Server();
    }
    public launchApp() {
        this.server.startServer();
    }

}
```

I tried to do

```
Server.prototype.startServer = jest.fn();
new Launcher.launchApp();
expect(Server.prototype.startServer).toBeCalled();
```

but it fails

Comment: what is the fail message? add it to the question

Comment: Did you try jest.mock? Read more: https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach worked for me. The only problem with your snippet was that you are not instantiating your `Launcher` properly. It needs to be:

```
Server.prototype.startServer = jest.fn();
new Launcher(). launchApp();
expect(Server.prototype.startServer).toBeCalled();
```

But if you are looking for other ways to mock methods in classes, there are many to achieve it, see: [Jest docs: The 4 ways to create an ES6 class mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#the-4-ways-to-create-an-es6-class-mock). One of the ways is described under: https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#mocking-non-default-class-exports

So you can use [`jest.mock()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) with your module path, then return an object with the key that is the same as the class export name.

```
const mockStartServer = jest.fn();
jest.mock("./Server/Server", () => {
  return {
    Server: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return { startServer: mockStartServer };
    }),
  };
});
```

Note that `mockStartServer` is defined and initialized with `jest.fn()` on the outer scope, and outside the returned object, and that's because Jest's `mock` behavior:

> *"Since calls to jest.mock() are hoisted to the top of the file, Jest
> prevents access to out-of-scope variables. By default, you cannot
> first define a variable and then use it in the factory. Jest will
> disable this check for variables that start with the word mock.
> However, it is still up to you to guarantee that they will be
> initialized on time. Be aware of [Temporal Dead Zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#temporal_dead_zone_tdz)"*. src: [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter)

Then the test would be:

```
import { Launcher } from "./luncher";
import { Server } from "./Server/Server";

const mockStartServer = jest.fn();

jest.mock("./Server/Server", () => {
  return {
    Server: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return { startServer: mockStartServer };
    }),
  };
});

it("should check for server start", () => {
  const luncher = new Launcher();
  luncher.launchApp();

  expect(mockStartServer).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

---

You can also create a mock with [`spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname), by overriding the implementation of the **spied** `Server.prototype.startServer` method.

```
const startServerMock = jest
  .spyOn(Server.prototype, "startServer")
  .mockImplementation(() => {});

it("should check for server start", () => {
  const lun = new Launcher();
  lun.launchApp();

  expect(startServerMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Thx for the feedback and the add-ons. I forgot calling constructor on Launcher.